# "SSL host could not be verified" error

Tags: eclipse, git, ssl, bitbucket, verification

Whenever I try to connect the git via eclipse mars, I entered the bitbucket URL as the instructions in this website.

http://crunchify.com/how-to-configure-bitbucket-git-repository-in-you-eclipse/

The problem occurred in the step 9 which is in the website link. Then when I click Next, the following errors occur.

> .git is missing at end of repository URL // I tried it but SSL verification error occurred again.)
>   SSL host could not be verified. (set http.sslVerify=false in Git configuration)

How can I solve that SSL host issue and pass to the step 10 which is the website link?

Comment: You need to be more specific; for example, what project are you trying to clone? Have you verified that you're using the right thing and can clone from the command line?

Comment: One of my teammates created a repository for our senior project. I signed up to bitbucket.org as well. My other teammate followed the same instructions but only I got error there. The name of the project is necessary to write here?

Answer (score 23):

In my experience it seems that it happens under Windows with certain configuration of Eclipse (not sure which ones).

Go in Eclipse Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration, and click "Add Entry..."

Put "http.sslVerify" as key and "false" as value (no quotes).

In the "clone repository" window put your user / password (don't leave "git", since there is no ssh-key configured under Windows, I suppose).

If needed, in the Git Repository view, check the properties of your new repository and double check that remote.origin.url has your username rather than "git" (otherwise during authentication you'll have a greyed out username textbox with "git" written in it).

Comment: Note: That sounds very much like "trust everybody whom you connect to that they are who you think they are". SSL provides at least a basic level of certified identity - you can be reasonably sure that the other party is the one they claim to be when you validate their certificate. Globally disabling that is a significantly bad idea. Might be an option for a very short test, but nothing for a long-term configuration

Comment: It does not make much sense to use an SSL secured connection, and at the same time switch off the verification.

Comment: Sometimes this is needed when behind corporate firewalls, unfortunately.