# SSL host could not be verified

Tags: eclipse, ssl, bitbucket, egit, verification

I am getting SSL host could not be verified in Eclipse while trying to pull a bitbucket git project.

I read this and it has no help:
["SSL host could not be verified" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663010/ssl-host-could-not-be-verified-error)

I changed the ssl verification false even downloaded Egit.
no difference. Still says the same thing.

I am started to pissed off by bitbucket as I couldn't do any development because of dealing with various issues. One of them was pull back forward also...

Can anyone help?
I didn't want to open a new discussion but my comment on that thread is deleted.

While entering the URI for the repository, do I need to enter the port number for https or SSH? In fact I tried by adding 443 to both but again no success.

I don't want to go to github and pay for private repository.

I would be grateful if you can help.

Comment: What is the URL you are trying ? Are you behind a corporate proxy ? check your network settings

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation. I am writing as answer (Stupid thing!)

I am not behind proxy.
This is the repository but it is private so you can not access I think.
https://cosai@bitbucket.org/cosai/uaon.git